# How to mimic jquery mobile page load

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have an application which have some images which are half colored on page load and later it changes as per logic...i have a restart button which should take back the application to the state it was when it was loaded for a first time (i.e. the images shuld be half colored )

Can this be done in jQuery mobile???

Comment: So can anyone tell me how to do this using jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pages are external documents then you can use the `reloadPage` option of the `$.mobile.changePage()` method to reload your external document to it's initial state.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#some-page-id", function () {
    $(this).find("a").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(this.href, { reloadPage : true });
        return false;
    });
});
```

> **reloadPage** (*boolean*, default: false) Forces a reload of a page, even
>   if it is already in the DOM of the page container. Used only when the
>   'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.
>
> Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html